# Why malloc can't work with strcpy?

Tags: c, string, function, malloc, strcpy

```
char * removeChar(char * str, char c){
    int len = strlen(str);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char * copy = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
    while(i < len){
        if(str[i] != c){
            copy[j] = str[i];
            j++;
            i++;
        }else{
            i++;
        }
   }

    if(strcmp(copy, str) != 0){
        strcpy(str,copy);

    }else{
        printf("Error");
    }
    return copy;
}




int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    char str[] = "Input string";
    char * input;
    input = removeChar(str,'g');
    printf("%s\n", input);
    free(input);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why every time I try to run it ,it always says uninitialized variable and sticks in the strcpy line and printf line.

Basically this function is to take a string, and a character and removes the  that character from the string (because I am learning malloc so that's why I wrote the function like this).

Comment: It appears to me that there are at least two lines of code missing after the end of the `if(strcmp(copy, str) != 0)` block.  Please add them.  (You can edit your question - see the tiny gray word "edit" under the blue "c" in a box?  That's a button.  Yes, really.)

Comment: I think you forgot to set the last byte of the string to `NUL` (`\0`).

Comment: I don't get that warning but a different one ~ *warning C4715: 'removeChar': not all control
paths return a value*. But seeing as I had to add a missing `}` perhaps I put it in the wrong place.

Comment: I don't get any uninitialized variable warnings either.  This code has several places where I wouldn't have done it that way, and the missing couple of lines are a problem, but the only actual _bug_ I see is the one pointed out by Alexander and Krom.

Comment: @Nina Liu  The function does not make sense. Describe in the question what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You have to copy also the last byte that's the byte used to close the "string" and it's value is 0. Then the `while` should be `while ( i <= len )`. Furthermore the `malloc` should allocate `sizeof(char)*len +1`.

Comment: ... The `if` inside the while doesn't need the else ... the variable `i` may be increased for each loop.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it removes the specified character from the input string. It works if it's the last one at least...

Comment: @gsamaras No, it does not. The function does not make any sense.

Answer (score 4):

After the while loop do:

```
copy[j] = '\0';
```

to `NULL`-terminate your string; that way it can work with methods coming from `<string.h>`, which assume that the string is nul-terminated.

---

PS: One warning you should see is about not returning `copy` in your function in any case, because now if the condition of the if statement is wrong, your function won't return something valid, so add this:

```
return copy;
```

at the end of your function (which is now corrected with your edit).

Other than that, the only warning you should still get are for the unused arguments of `main()`, nothing else:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:32:14: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
              ^~~~
prog.c:32:27: warning: unused parameter 'argv' [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
                           ^~~~
```

Comment: Nitpick: NULL is a pointer.  Strings are NUL-terminated, with only one L.

Comment: @zwol: which is why almost exclusively say "zero-terminated" now.  Less confusing.

Answer (score 3):

While you copy over bytes from `str` to `copy`, you don't add a terminating null byte at the end.  As a result, `strcmp` reads past the copied characters into unitialized memory, possibly past the end of the allocated memory block.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

After your `while` loop, add a terminating null byte to `copy`.

Also, you never return a value if the `if` block at the end is false.  You need to return something for that, probably the copied string.

```
char * removeChar(char * str, char c){
    int len = strlen(str);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char * copy = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
    while(i < len){
        if(str[i] != c){
            copy[j] = str[i];
            j++;
            i++;
        }else{
            i++;
        }
    }
    //  add terminating null byte
    copy[j] = '\0';

    if(strcmp(copy, str) != 0){
       strcpy(str,copy);
    }
    // always return copy
    return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You never initialised input and the some compilers don't notice,
that the the value is never used before the line

```
input = removeChar(str, 'g');
```

in your code. So they emit the diagnostic just to be sure.

```
strcpy(str, copy)
```

gets stuck in your code, as copy never got a closing 0 byte and
so depends on the nondeterministic content of your memory at the
moment of the allocation of the memory backing copy, how long strcpy
will run and if you get eventually a SIGSEGV (or similar).

`strcpy` will loop until it finds a 0 byte in your memory.

Answer (score 0):

For starters to remove a character from a string there is no need to create dynamically a character array and then copy this array into the original string.

Either you should write a function that indeed removes the specified character from a string or a function that creates a new string based on the source string excluding the specified character.

It is just a bad design that only confuses users. That is the function is too complicated and uses redundant functions like `malloc`, `strlen`, `strcmp` and `strcpy`. And in fact it has a side effect that is not obvious. Moreover there is used incorrect type `int` for the length of a string instead of the type `size_t`.

As for your function implementation then you forgot to append the terminating zero '\0' to the string built in the dynamically allocated array.

If you indeed want to remove a character from a string then the function can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * remove_char(char *s, char c)
{
    char *p = s;

    while (*p && *p != c) ++p;

    for ( char *q = p; *p++; )
    {
        if (*p != c) *q++ = *p;
    }

    return s;
}

int main( void )
{
    char str[] = "Input string";

    puts(str);
    puts(remove_char(str, 'g'));

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Input string
Input strin
```

If you are learning the function `malloc` and want to use it you in any case should try to implement a correct design.

To use `malloc` you could write a function that creates a new string based on the source string excluding the specified character. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * remove_copy_char(const char *s, char c)
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for (const char *p = s; *p; ++p)
    {
        if (*p != c) ++n;
    }

    char *result = malloc(n + 1);

    if (result)
    {
        char *q = result;

        for (; *s; ++s)
        {
            if (*s != c) *q++ = *s;
        }

        *q = '\0';
    }

    return result;
}

int main( void )
{
    char *str = "Input string";

    puts(str);

    char *p = remove_copy_char(str, 'g');

    if ( p ) puts(p );

    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

The program output will be the same as above.

```
Input string
Input strin
```

Pay attention to the function declaration

```
char * remove_copy_char(const char *s, char c);
                        ^^^^^^
```

In this case the source string can be a string literal.

```
char *str = "Input string";
```